# Can't retrieve data from influxDB locally hosted on raspberry PI

Tags: node.js, influxdb, influxdb-2

I'm trying to use a node.js express back-end to retrieve data from an influxdb database hosted locally on raspberry pi. The server program is also running on raspberry PI. I'm not getting any authorization errors. I'm just getting an empty response when I use the read API for influxDB, despite there being data points in the database.

My read function goes something like this:

```
let database = `Test_data`

const client_1 = new client.InfluxDBClient({ host: 'http://localhost:8086/', token: token, org:'org_name' })

const query = "SELECT * FROM 'Device status'" 
const rows = await client_1.query(query, database)
return rows
```

While I can retrieve data from an influx cloud db, the same code doesn't work for a locally hosted influxdb.

Any reason this could happen?